# Advice Needed in verifying the logic of the solution

Tags: python-3.x, combinations

I am attempting a competitive programming question, and I am sure that the logic used in implementing this is correct. I would request the help of other StackOverflow users to help me regarding the same

The question is as follows:

Brian built his car and was confused about what name he should keep for it. 
He asked Roman for help. Roman being his good friend, suggested a lot of names. Brian only liked names that:

- Consisted of exactly three distinct characters, say C1, C2, and C3
- Satisfied the criteria that the string was of the form - C1n C2n C3n: This means, first C1 occurs n times, then C2 occurs n times, and then C3 occurs n times. For example, xyz, ccaarr, mmmiiiaaa satisfy the criteria, but xyzw, aabbbcccc don't.

Given N names suggested by Roman, print "OK" if Brian likes the name and "Not OK" if he doesn't.

So the Python code for this is as follows-

```
no_of_cases=int(input())

for value in range(no_of_cases):
dictionary={}

car_name=input()

for value in car_name:
    dictionary[value]=dictionary.get(value,0)+1

if len(dictionary)==3:
    count_list=list(dictionary.values())
    name_list=list(dictionary.keys())
    if ((count_list[0]==count_list[1]==count_list[2])):
        c1=name_list[0]*count_list[0]+name_list[1]*count_list[0]+name_list[2]*count_list[0]
        c6=name_list[0]*count_list[0]+name_list[2]*count_list[0]+name_list[1]*count_list[0]
        c2=name_list[1]*count_list[0]+name_list[2]*count_list[0]+name_list[0]*count_list[0]
        c5=name_list[1]*count_list[0]+name_list[0]*count_list[0]+name_list[2]*count_list[0]
        c3=name_list[2]*count_list[0]+name_list[0]*count_list[0]+name_list[1]*count_list[0]
        c4=name_list[2]*count_list[0]+name_list[1]*count_list[0]+name_list[2]*count_list[0]
        if car_name==c1 or car_name==c2 or car_name==c3 or car_name== c4 or car_name==c5 or car_name==c6:
            print("OK")
        else:
            print("Not OK")
    else:
        print("Not OK")
else:
    print("Not OK")
```

Sample Input/Output-

`bbbrrriii-OK`

`brian-NOT OK`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct but you have complicated the logic, even then it will produce correct output.

Here is a simple version:

```
no_of_cases=int(input())

for value in range(no_of_cases):
    car_name=input()
    name_length = len(car_name)
    correct = True if name_length%3==0 else False
    if correct:
        each_length = name_length//3
        first,mid,last=car_name[0],car_name[each_length],car_name[-1]
        if (first!=last) and (first!=mid) and (last!=mid):
            if car_name!=(first*each_length+mid*each_length+last*each_length):
                correct=False
        else:
            correct=False

    if correct:
        print("Ok")
    else:
        print("Not Ok")
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic for this program @WAS?

Comment: I have modified code a bit. car_name have 3 characters of N length so car_name should be a multiple of three. first character is at 0 , mid is at N, last at -1. so take each character multiply with length,you have new string. if new string is equal to car_name so car_name is valid.